# custom android softkeyboard for a particular application

Tags: android, keyboard, soft-keyboard

I have created a custom softkeyboard. It works for all the application throughout.

Is it possible to create a softkeyboard so that it can work for a particular application not for all the application.

Any ideas.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) is good explanation of different ways to achieve this.

The **Android Nethack application** has a complete and clear source code example of how to create a custom keyboard for an application, how to display it on screen and how to define multiple keyboard layouts. It contains pretty much everything you need to know.

It is by far the best example I have seen.

http://code.google.com/p/nethack-android/

Answer (score 0):

Umm, I guess you could integrate your own soft keyboard within your application - and never show the real one. Much work though, but I guess it could be done.

However you cannot force a certain soft keyboard to a certain application, but lots of keyboards support different styles using this in the XML:

`android:inputType=""`

Perhaps one of those would suit you?

For example if you'd like a keyboard fit for input in the form of email-addresses:

`android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"`

Comment: Thanks Joakim for your answers. But right now what is happening is, I created a softkeyboard and then installed in on my phone or emulator. Then I need to activate it from setting->Language and keyboard. Then if i need to use this custom created keyboard then I need to hold any of the EditText. Then choose the inputmenthod.  But what I want is, I need to create that softkeyboard so that I may not follow above steps and by default my custom keyboard can work on my application only. Please advise.

Comment: I don't think that is possible.